# How do I check for duplicate rows and do calculate on that rows in excel file?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, weighted-average

I have one excel file which is having data like following

```
CUSIP   Quantity  Date           Price
AF0      500000   5/6/2013      1
AE4      400000   5/6/2013      1.0825
AE4      500      5/6/2013      1
```

I need to check for column `CUSIP` and `Date`
If I'm having duplicate `CUSIP` for same `date` then I need to do following calculation.

> 1.Need to add `Quantity` for both of them instead of showing duplicate records need to show only one record( sum of Quantity).
>
> 2.Need to do calculation on Price as well like following

```
NewPrice = ((400000 * 1.0825) + (500 * 1.00))/(400000 + 500) = 1.08148
```

For example in using above data
Need to show output like

```
CUSIP   Quantity  Date          Price
AF0     500000    5/6/2013      1
AE4     400500    5/6/2013      1.082397004
```

How do I achieve this in excel file using LOOKUP or else ?

Comment: is a pivot table a viable answer in your application?

Comment: All data is in simple excel file only NO Pivot table used.. I just need to take out duplicate records based on same dates inside excel file only

Comment: My file is having more than 20,000 records So 
How do I check within that for duplicate CUSIP based on same date 
please give me any thread or link to do this

`Please give me an example how I can use VBA in my case`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after quite some research (interesting question by the way!), I came up with this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"",SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),B:B,D:D)/SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
```

Put these in cell D2 and E2 respectively (which is the next column after `Price` and in the row of CUSIP `AF0`).

And fill to the bottom of the worksheet to get the weighted average price or each CUSIP.

The first formula gives you the total quantity for the CUSIP and the second gives you the average price.

Copy and paste values for those two columns after calculation.

Put a filter and remove all the rows where the total quantity and average price is blank, and sort to make the worksheet neat.

Let me know if this works for you! I tried it on your sample data and it seems to be working. It's my first time using `SUMPRODUCT` ^^;

---

`SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2)`

This bit returns the rows from column A where it equals to the row's CUSIP.

`SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),B:B,D:D`

This additional bit tells excel to multiply the values in column B and D of each returned row found above and `SUMPRODUCT` adds each result together.

**EDIT:**
I actually forgot about the date. You could maybe add a helper column where you'll generate an identifier to separate the different dates. To make it, you'll have to make a `concatenate`.

Hence in cell F2, you put:

```
 =CONCATENATE(A2,C2)
```

In the formulae for cells D2 and E2, you will have to change them so they become:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)>1,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
=IF(COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)>1,"",SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),B:B,D:D)/SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))
```

reEDIT: Oops, put the wrong reference. Fixed now.